# Block execution until children called via MPI_Comm_spawn have finished, no access to children

Tags: fortran, mpi, spawn

I would like to spawn the child.exe from the main.f90 code, and I don't have access to modify the child.f90. A simplified code looks like:

**main.f90:**

```
program main
   implicit none
   include 'mpif.h'
   integer, parameter:: root = 0
   integer, dimension(:), allocatable:: errCodes, status
   integer:: numprocs, request, ierr, taskid, INTERCOMM
   character*(*), PARAMETER:: cmd = "./child.exe"
!
   call mpi_init(ierr)
   call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, taskid, ierr)
   call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, numprocs, ierr )
   call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!   
   allocate( errCodes(numprocs), status(numprocs))
   print*, "from parent, CPU: ", taskid
   call MPI_COMM_SPAWN(cmd, MPI_ARGV_NULL, 2, MPI_INFO_NULL, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD,INTERCOMM, errCodes, ierr)
!
   call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!
   print*, "After children, from parent CPU", taskid
   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

**child.f90:**

```
 program child
   implicit none
   include 'mpif.h'
   integer:: numprocs, temp, ierr, arg_count, taskid, maxproces, errCodes(2)
!  
   call mpi_init(ierr)
   call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, taskid, ierr)
   call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, numprocs, ierr )
!   
   call sleep(1)
!
   print*, "from child, CPU: ", taskid
   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program child
```

My question is similar to [this one in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950762/block-execution-until-children-called-via-mpi-comm-spawn-have-finished), but I would appreciate it if someone could clarify how to do the process if I don't have access to the children. I have tried to use mpi_barrier, but it is not helpful.

Comment: What means :it is not helpful"?

Comment: BTW include `mpif.h` is more for compatibility with FORTRAN 77, I would recommend `use mpi` in Fortran 90 and newer.

Comment: I have added a mpi_barrier so that I can see the printed message from the main after the printed message from the child. What actually happens is that the main program does not wait for the child to finish its execution.

Comment: See the answer, your communicators were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For me the Hristo's advice from the linked answer works quite well, just follow it closely. Pay attention to the communicators (`INTERCOMM`, `parent`). There is still some problem at the end, I have never worked with child processes before, but it should point you to the right direction.

```
program main
   use mpi
   implicit none
   integer, parameter:: root = 0
   integer, dimension(:), allocatable:: errCodes, status
   integer:: numprocs, request, ierr, taskid, INTERCOMM
   character*(*), PARAMETER:: cmd = "./child.exe"
!
   call mpi_init(ierr)
   call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, taskid, ierr)
   call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, numprocs, ierr )
   call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
!   
   allocate( errCodes(numprocs), status(numprocs))
   print*, "from parent, CPU: ", taskid
   call MPI_COMM_SPAWN(cmd, MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, INTERCOMM, errCodes, ierr)
!
   call mpi_barrier(INTERCOMM, ierr)
!
   call mpi_barrier(INTERCOMM, ierr)

   print*, "After children, from parent CPU", taskid

   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main


 program child
   use mpi
   implicit none
   integer:: numprocs, temp, ierr, arg_count, taskid, maxproces, errCodes(2), parent
!  
   call mpi_init(ierr)
   call mpi_Comm_get_parent(parent, ierr)
   call mpi_comm_rank(parent, taskid, ierr)
   call mpi_comm_size(parent, numprocs, ierr )
!   
   call sleep(5)
   call mpi_barrier(parent, ierr)
!
   print*, "from child, CPU: ", taskid
   call sleep(1)

   call mpi_barrier(parent, ierr)

!    call sleep(2)
   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program child
```

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with it. when I run it using "mpirun -np 2 a.out" it continues to print the first message from main.f90 before calling the children and does not print the message from child.f90 or the message in main.f90 after the spawn.

Comment: Why do you run with `-np 2`?

Comment: It actually works for me even with `-np 2`, but I cannot say it will work everywhere. But of course it will print the first line twice then.

Comment: To be able to set the number of CPUs I would like to use. Even when I use a.out to run the executable generated from main.f90, I get numerous "from parent, CPU: 0" printed on the screen.

Comment: This is a test code, and it might not make sense to call it with more than one processor.

Comment: Do you run *exactly* the version which is now in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from the answer. Also, I cannot change the content of the child program I am trying to combine with my own code. I see that you have made some modifications on it.

Comment: Did you copy it from this version of the answer (check it)? Yes, I did some changes. Test my code first, only after it works and you understand it, start to adapt your original code. Some of the changes are important.

Comment: See the sentence "There is still some problem at the end,..., but it should point you to the right direction." I do not claim it is perfect.